# Efficient way to remove duplicate strings after adding their key values

Tags: c++, sorting, time-limit-exceeded

How can I remove duplicate strings from a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>>` after adding the `int` members of the pair and sorting them by their `string` members?

For example:

```
abc   4
abc   3
xy    1
xyzw  12
xy    4
abc   14
```

should produce the result:

```
abc   21
xyzw  12
xy    5
```

I have actually used `std::vector<Mystruct>` as the data structure, with:

```
struct Mystruct
{
    string s;
    int e;
};
```

and sorted them with respect to their string values and linearly iterated by adding the keys and removing duplicates, and again sorted according to their key values and ended up getting Time Limit Exceeded.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#define ull unsigned long long
struct vec
{
    string s;
    ull e;
};
bool compare(vec v1, vec v2) {
    return v1.s < v2.s;
}
bool comparenum(vec v1, vec v2) {
    return v1.e < v2.e;
}
int main() {
    int q;
    cin >> q;
    string ss;
    ull ee;
    vector<vec> v(q);
    for (int i = 0; i<q; i++) {
        cin >> ss >> ee;
        v[i].s = ss;
        v[i].e = ee;
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (v[i + 1].s == v[i].s) {
            v[i].e = v[i].e + v[i + 1].e;
            v.erase(v.begin() + i + 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparenum);
    for (vec vv : v) {
        cout << vv.s << " " << vv.e << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add your full code please. Still, best way is without any sorting and using map<string, int> to count them

Comment: @juvian how can i use map to count can you explain in detail

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but if it is what I think it is, you should read the [help/on-topic], think about it and probably remove this question. Also, stop using single letter variable names. It's unreadable.

Comment: I assume this is for a class. The secret here is that you are using the wrong container. Check your notes. There is a container that does this all automatically with no action by you needed.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: @Vogel612 his code does work, although not fast enough for his task. A performance tag might have been more appropiate though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Performance review:**

Your biggest bottleneck is the `v.erase(v.begin() + i + 1);`, which is turning your algorithm from being **O(n log n)** to **O(n^2)**. A simple way to fix this is using a new vector and input the unique keys intead of removing duplicated ones from your old vector.

```
vector<vec> v2;
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (v[i + 1].s == v[i].s) {
        sum += v[i].s;
    } else {
        v2.push_back(new vec(v[i].s, sum + v[i].s)); 
        sum = 0;
    }
}

sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), comparenum);

for (vec vv : v2) {
    cout << vv.s << " " << vv.e << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Avoid `using namespace std;`

Importing all names of a namespace is a bad habit to get into, and can cause surprise when names like `begin` and `size` are in the global namespace.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

The exceptions to this rule are namespaces explicitly intended to be imported wholesale, such as the `std::literals` namespaces.

## Avoid preprocessor macros

If you want a shorter name for a type, it's much safer to write

```
using ull = unsigned long long;
```

Personally, I'd give it a name that reflects what I want to *use* it for, rather than what it (currently) *is*.

## Improve naming

What's the significance of `vec` as a name?  It's confusingly similar to `vector`, but it's used as an element of a vector.  Similarly, its members `s` and `e` convey nothing - consider `name` and `count`, if that's what they represent.

## Simplify the logic

It's a lot easier to accumulate counts if you introduce a `std::map` to hold the sums:

```
std::map<std::string,ull> accumulator;
for (auto const& element: v)
    accumulator[element.s] += element.e;

// write them back into the vector
v.clear();
for (auto const& element: accumulator)
    v.push_back(vec{element.first, element.second});
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do this would be to use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

If you're concerned with the extra memory usage and/or speed of that (either of which could be entirely justifiable) you might want to consider a sequence something like:

1. sort items
2. add values with identical keys (about which, see below)
3. use `std::unique` to isolate the duplicates
4. use `erase` to remove the isolated duplicates

`std::unique` is required to keep the *first* item out of a set of duplicates, so we know that if we arrange the items with the summed value first, then the other duplicates, it'll keep the one we want.

The standard library provides `std::partial_sum`, which does pretty much the summing we want, with the exception that it doesn't (automatically) re-start the sum when the key changes. Fortunately, it does let us supply a binary operation to implement the summing, so we can supply a binary op that returns the sum of the previous value and the current value if their keys are the same, or the current value unchanged if the key has changed.

One other minor detail though: if we apply `std::partial_sum` the most obvious way, it'll produce the sum of equal values as the *last* item in a sequence of identical keys, rather than the first (where we want it to be for `std::unique` to keep it). The obvious way to correct that is to apply `partial_sum` in the reverse direction.

Putting all these together, we might end up with code on this general order:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct kv {
    std::string key;
    unsigned long long value;

    bool operator<(kv const &other) { return key < other.key; }

    bool operator==(kv const &other) { return key == other.key; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, kv const &k) {
        return os << k.key << " : " << k.value;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<kv> inputs{
        { "abc",    4 },
        { "abc",    3 },
        { "xy",     1 },
        { "xyzw",  12 },
        { "xy",     4 },
        { "abc",   14 }
    };

    std::sort(inputs.begin(), inputs.end());

    std::partial_sum(inputs.rbegin(), inputs.rend(), 
        inputs.rbegin(), 
        [&](kv &acc, kv const &v) { 
            if (v.key == acc.key) acc.value += v.value; 
            else acc = v; 
            return acc; });

    inputs.erase(std::unique(inputs.begin(), inputs.end()), inputs.end());

    std::sort(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), 
              [](kv const &a, kv const &b) { return b.value < a.value; });

    std::copy(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), std::ostream_iterator<kv>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

As to code style, I think we can see a few obvious items:

1. The key-value pair probably deserves a better name than "vec". I've named it "kv", but in almost any real situation, there's almost certain to be a better name than that as well.
2. Likewise, I've used `key` and `value` as the names of the members. Again, for real use these should relate to the actual items involved--perhaps "name" and "height", or "item" and "quantity".
3. Standard algorithms can simplify a lot of the rest of the code quite a bit.
4. Be wary of directly erasing items from a vector unless you (one way or another) move them to the end first. Otherwise, each erasure can turn out as an O(N) operation.
5. When you need to specify an ordering for a sort, it's *generally* preferable to specify it as a lambda rather than a free function. If it's complex enough that a lambda isn't convenient, it's generally better to implement it as a functor (class that overloads `operator()`) instead of a free function. When you use a function, that's a lot more likely to result in it generating an actual function call instead of generating the code inline.